# Check session before login page request

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make my login page to check if the session is already running then just route to the home page but since my login page is an angular modal so whenever i put the if condition it does check but it first show the modal view and then check if the session is running or not and if it finds the session running it goes to home page but shows the home page in the modal view which is not its default view. Here is the link to the view i am getting [picture](https://ibb.co/bvuJgK) . But my homepage looks like this [homepage](https://ibb.co/fR8uMK) .

Here is my login page html code

```
<div class="card" id="LoginArea" [@routerTransition]>
<div background="../../assets/images/bghome.jpg">
<div #cardBody class="body">     
    <form #loginForm="ngForm" id="LoginForm" method="post" novalidate (ngSubmit)="login()">
            <h4 class="text-center">{{l("LogIn")}} 
                <span *ngIf="tenantName"> in to  {{tenantName | uppercase }}@</span>
            </h4>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div class="change-tenant-anchor">
                        <a  routerLink="/account/workspace">Change Workspace</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="material-icons">person</i>
            </span>
            <div class="form-line">
                <input materialInput [(ngModel)]="loginService.authenticateModel.userNameOrEmailAddress" autoFocus class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username or Email" name="userNameOrEmailAddress" required maxlength="255" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="material-icons">lock</i>
            </span>
            <div class="form-line">
                <input materialInput type="password" [(ngModel)]="loginService.authenticateModel.password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="{{l('Password')}}" required maxlength="32">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 p-t-5">
                <input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="loginService.rememberMe" name="rememberMe" id="rememberme" class="filled-in chk-col-pink" value="true">
                <label for="rememberme">{{l("RememberMe")}}</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 p-t-5">
                <a [routerLink]="['/account/password-reset']">Forgot password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <button id="LoginButton" class="btn btn-block bg-pink waves-effect" type="submit">{{l("LogIn")}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

        </div>

        <div class="row m-t-15 m-b--20" *ngIf="isSelfRegistrationAllowed">

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Typescript code

```
import { AppConsts } from '@shared/AppConsts';
import { Component, Injector, ElementRef, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation, 
OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/app-component-base';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { accountModuleAnimation } from '@shared/animations/routerTransition';
import { AbpSessionService } from '@abp/session/abp-session.service';
import { SharedDataService } from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
import { IsTenantAvailableInput } from '@shared/service-proxies/service- 
proxies';
import { AccountServiceProxy, EmailConfirmationDto } from '@shared/service- 
proxies/service-proxies';

 @Component({
 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
 styleUrls: [
    './login.component.less'
 ],
 animations: [accountModuleAnimation()]
 })
 export class LoginComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit {

 @ViewChild('cardBody') cardBody: ElementRef;

 submitting: boolean = false;
 tenantName: string | undefined;
 user: EmailConfirmationDto = new EmailConfirmationDto();

 active: boolean = false;
 saving: boolean = false;

 constructor(
    injector: Injector,
    public loginService: LoginService,
    private _router: Router,
    private _sessionService: AbpSessionService,
    private _sharedDataService: SharedDataService
 ) {
    super(injector);

    if (this._sharedDataService.getMessage()) {
        this.tenantName = this._sharedDataService.getMessage();
        this._sharedDataService.setId(undefined);
    } else if (this._sharedDataService.getId()) {
        this.tenantName = undefined;
        this._sharedDataService.setId(undefined);
    } else {
        this.tenantName = (!this.appSession.tenant ? undefined : 
 this.appSession.tenant.tenancyName);
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
    if(this._sessionService.userId) {
        this._router.navigate(['/app/home']);
    }
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $(this.cardBody.nativeElement).find('input:first').focus();
}

get multiTenancySideIsTeanant(): boolean {
    return this._sessionService.tenantId > 0;
}

get isSelfRegistrationAllowed(): boolean {
    if (!this._sessionService.tenantId) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

login(): void {
    this.submitting = true;
    this.loginService.authenticate(
        () => this.submitting = false
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of login component, you have to check session exist into **app.component.ts** file ngOnInit() and if a session exists then route to home page else redirect to login page.

Comment: No it does not work, i put the condition statement to check if the session is present or not but all it does is show me the login page but it also destroyed the view of the login page. Thing is i am dealing with multitenancy here and even though from app.component i am just calling the login page modal like this `ngOnInit(): void {
        $('body').attr('class', 'login-page');
    }` putting the conditional check for session is not helpful at all.